# service postgresql start [falló] Centos 6.9

Tags: postgresql, centos, servidor, servicio

estoy intentando crear un servidor en Centos con postgresql en una maquina virtual, tengo otra maquina virtual desde la que me quiero conectar pero necesito levantar el servicio postgresql en la maquina servidor, al escribir el comando "service postgresql start" me arroja el mensaje "Iniciando servicios postgresql:  [Falló]" y nada más, es extraño porque hace unos momentos atrás lo iniciaba correctamente pero al reiniciar la maquina virtual comenzó a fallar, a que puede deberse este problema?

Saludos, desde ya muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Has revisado los logs? Sería importante que insertaras el resultado de los logs de posgrest o syslog para poderte ayudar.